# Where to ask these questions?

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking, knowledge

Here on SE I've only answered questions so far, so I thought it was time to ask some of my own. But where should I go to find the answers to these questions?

1. Would a *tsubo-niwa* garden help with my kung-fu novel, "Big Blind"?
2. Does the Qur'an state anything about graduate students using plastic building blocks while abroad studying encryption algorithms?
3. Would it count as prior art if I used a Turing machine as a UHF transmitter for my cat, Gatto?

Comment: You ass. You really had me fooled that this was going to be a question about puzzles. And now I'm stuck trying to figure out this thing. *sigh*, lemme go get my pen and paper.

Comment: you packed as many SE sites as you can in there, didn't you. lol

Comment: So far, I have identified "japanese, gardening, martial-arts, writers, poker, islam, academia, legos, travel, cryptography, patents, computer-science, amateur-radio, pets, italian" but some sites overlap, like radio amateur radio and electronics.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah I was worried about overlaps being misleading, but the sites you've identified are all correct.

Comment: I'm thinking Baconian cipher, beta sites vs non-beta...?

Comment: Domo ori gatto mr roboto?

Comment: You made me think this was a question for meta stack exchange. I almost VTC'd it lol!

Comment: *I've answered a lot of questions on PSE, so I thought it was time to ask some of my own.* Is this important to the puzzle? If not please edit it out (or I will do so)

Comment: @warspyking That's not important to the puzzle, but I added it for flavor.

Comment: So it's more storyline than meta information?

Comment: @warspyking Yes, but it also clues that the puzzle has something to do with SE.

Comment: Alright gotchya. Just making sure because generally meta information shouldn't be in the question (and I figured better double-check before removing it myself.

Comment: Can I recommend changing 'PSE' to 'SE' though? Sounds like you want to ask them on Puzzling.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah - I think "would it count" might be maths. And "algorithms" could possibly be programmers, or maybe stackoverflow or codereview.

Comment: @f" - is there one single answer to the entire thing, or is it three separate answers, one for each of the three questions?

Comment: @GlenO There is a single answer.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah's list is complete, but (as was guessed) you still have to make some connections.

Comment: Ask it here: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: Weird.  There's no way I'm even going to try to figure this one out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please ask your questions in

> http://area51.stackexchange.com/

To solve this question, you need to determine all the stack exchange sites, taking note of which sentence and which order they appear in.  @RespectMyAuthoritah has thankfully done this for me:

1. japanese, gardening, martial-arts, writers, poker
2. islam, academia, legos, travel, cryptography
3. patents, computer-science, amateur-radio, pets, italian

Now go to http://stackexchange.com/sites# and look up the positions of each stack exchange site.  For each of the 3 questions, connect the five stack exchange sites in order to reveal a character for each site.

[Big picture incoming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iEuP.png)

And we get A51, or Area 51.

If you interpret 5 as S, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/?as=1 is also another answer.

Comment: That's awesome. Kudos for not actually using ciphers and crap which just makes most of the puzzles like this obnoxious.